# about labplot installation

Tags: software-installation, add-apt-repository

When I was using ubuntu 10.04. labplot 1.6 was in the repository but in ubuntu 14.10 it is not there.New version of labplot 2 is relied for other destro but not for ubuntu. I tried to install .rpm pkg using alien conversion of .deb but error came.

please help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can download .deb version from the Debian site and install it using Software Centre or Gdebi.

http://linuxappfinder.com/package/labplot

Comment: I also tried that but I got error: Dependency is not satisfiable: kdelibs4c2a(>=4:3.5.9)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with packages built for different distributions I would suggest building *labplot* from source:

1. Download it from SoureForge ([v2.0.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/labplot/files/labplot/2.0.0/labplot-2.0.1.tar.bz2/download)
2. Unpack it (`tar xjf labplot-2.0.1.tar.bz2`)
3. Have a look at the *INSTALL* file in the unpacked directory and follow the instructions there.

   - You might need to install the *build-essential* package (`sudo apt-get install build-essential`) for the needed compilers and programs first.
   - *labplot* depends on Qt4.7 or newer, so you also need to install at least the Qt development packages (`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`)

Comment: hi,I saw following things "To build LabPlot just execute
# ./compile
Edit the compile script if you want to use options different from default ones.
E.g. specify a custom installation path via 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local

or build a debug build via
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = DebugFull

================================================================================
To install LabPlot execute

# cd build
# make install"   and did up to make install but I got "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop." error

Comment: Also for ./compile I got error  "
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:98 (message):
  ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
  /home/shrikant/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/shrikant/Videos/labplot-2.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".